# Create PDF and then Redirect

Tags: php, pdf, redirect

I am creating PDF with the following code

```
$pdf = new Pdf( $values );
$pdf->generate();
header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
header("Pragma: public");
```

This code is working fine and generating PDF, but now i want to redirect the page to some other link for eg

```
header("location:index.php");
```

But when I add this code in the end it only redirects to index.php and not create PDF.

Comment: What code is this written in?  PHP?

Comment: Yes. As i can see PHP. You want to give pdf and then redirect, or just in background create pdf and redirect?

Comment: Ok, so why do you want to create a PDF, then immediately leave the page?  What is your goal here?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have a button on the page "Save and create PDF" , when user press this it will save the page and create pdf and redirect user to home page (client requirement )

Comment: Is there any way to set header target. For example header('Window-target: _blank); for pdf and header('Window-target:_parent) for redirect.

Comment: Well, as I know if there is right Content-type clients browser will guess that there is pdf, and wouldn't open that page, just gives you a popup-download-dialog. You can give an timeout in 20 sec to save pdf, and after that redirect whereever you want. I don't think it's possible to do in your way...

Answer (score 0):

The trouble you have on that page is when someone visits it, headers have been sent, then followed by the output (Download attachment), so sending headers again will fail.

You need to do this on the page before, such as a "Click here to download PDF" - Make that "Click" button redirect to a page that opens a popup window which downloads your PDF and on the parent page (not the popup), redirect that one.

EXAMPLE:

when they click "Download", redirect to something you make up "index.php?download=true", obviously the $_GET["download"] is your trigger, so as your HTML code, make a popup window go to a download url for your PDF.

Comment: Is there any way to set header target. For example header('Window-target: _blank); for pdf and header('Window-target:_parent) for redirect.

Comment: target="_blank" in your HTML, not in PHP